# Special characters lost after converting html to GoogleDocs

Tags: javascript, html, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have uploaded an HTML to Google Drive using GoogleDriveAPI.
Also I set the convert option to true. It successfully converted and uploaded to GoogleDrive. I tried opening the converted file in GoogleDocs. But some italian specials characters are not showing correctly. 
Have any idea??

Comment: I tried both HTML4 and HTML5 doctypes

Comment: paste the HTTP request and response into your question